# Failed to push some refs to [github_repo_link]

Tags: github, push

I have a repo that is empty and i want to add to it some files but the problem that these files are 50GB so i use LFS or large file storage in github and then i add the files and then i commit them but the problem came when I want to push them to the repo an error occurs to me:
Error: failed to push some refs to [github_repo_link]

And I searched in the internet but nothing solve it i tried:

```
Git pull —rebase origin main 

Git pull origin main

Git push -f origin main

Git config —global pull.rebase true

Git config —global rebase.autoStash true
```

But nothing work, so please help if u can

Answer (score 1):

GitHub LFS have file size limit of 2GB for free accounts and 5GB for GitHub Enterprise Cloud users.
[About Git Large File Storage](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/working-with-files/managing-large-files/about-git-large-file-storage#about-git-large-file-storage)